# Creating an ArrayList from data in a text file

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a program that uses two classes to find the total $ amount from a text file of retail transactions.  The first class must read the file, and the second class must perform the calculations.  The problem I am having is that in the first class, the ArrayList only seems to get the price of the last item in the file.  Here is the input (which is in a text file):

$69.99 3 Shoes

$79.99 1 Pants

$17.99 1 Belt

And here is my first class:

```
class ReadInputFile {
static ArrayList<Double> priceArray = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<Double> quantityArray = new ArrayList<>();

static String  priceSubstring = new String();
static String quantitySubstring = new String();

public void gatherData () {

String s = "C:\\filepath";   
try {


      FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(s);

      BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

      String line;

      String substring = " ";

      while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null)


      substring = line.substring(1, line.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);



     priceSubstring = substring.substring(0,substring.indexOf(" "));

      quantitySubstring = substring.substring(substring.indexOf(" ") + 1 , substring.lastIndexOf(" ") );


      double price = Double.parseDouble(priceSubstring);
      double quantity = Double.parseDouble(quantitySubstring);

      priceArray.add(price);
      quantityArray.add(quantity);

      System.out.println(priceArray);


} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The output and value of priceArray is [17.99], but the desired output is [69.99,79.99,17.99].

Not sure where the problem is, but thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you have is:

```
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    substring = line.substring(1, line.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
}

priceSubstring = substring.substring(0,substring.indexOf(" "));

quantitySubstring = substring.substring(substring.indexOf(" ") + 1 , substring.lastIndexOf(" ") );


double price = Double.parseDouble(priceSubstring);
double quantity = Double.parseDouble(quantitySubstring);

priceArray.add(price);
quantityArray.add(quantity);

System.out.println(priceArray);
```

So all you are doing is creating a `substring` of the line you just read, then reading the next line, so basically, only the `substring` of the last will get processed by the remaining code.

Wrap the code in `{...}` which you want to be executed on each iteration of the loop

For example...

```
while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
    substring = line.substring(1, line.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
    priceSubstring = substring.substring(0,substring.indexOf(" "));

    quantitySubstring = substring.substring(substring.indexOf(" ") + 1 , substring.lastIndexOf(" ") );

    double price = Double.parseDouble(priceSubstring);
    double quantity = Double.parseDouble(quantitySubstring);

    priceArray.add(price);
    quantityArray.add(quantity);

    System.out.println(priceArray);
}
```

This will execute all the code within the `{...}` block for each line of the file

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling it was something simple but that had me stuck for quite awhile.  This worked perfectly, will accept when 10 minutes are up.

Comment: I'm glad it could help. Even if I have a single of code to execute, I always wrap it in a `{...}` block, might sound silly, but, one, I find it easier to read and two, you don't make mistakes like this one ;)